# How can I mount an OS X shared folder from Linux with smbmount?

Tags: macos, network, unix, mount, smb

I've tried searching this question in multiple ways, but it always seems to turn up results for mounting *from* OS X either from the Finder or from command line. However, what I'm trying to do is mount a shared folder that is on an OS X host using `smbmount` (or `mount.cifs` / `mount.smbfs`) on a Linux box (specifically, a ReadyNAS).

The general command like this results in an error:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/SVNbackup /mnt/SVNbackup -o user=bobtheuser,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw
```

...and I'm getting back

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

After some digging, I seem to find that I can list the shares on the OS X box by disabling signing, e.g.

```
smbclient //192.168.1.2 -o user=bobtheuser --signing=off
```

This works by reporting the shares, but still errors when it gets to the bottom reporting something about NT disconnection. As well, I don't believe there is a signing option on the `smbmount` command anyway. I have read some pages which suggest it might have something to do with NetBIOS over TCP/IP, but I don't see how that gets enabled in OS X and I already do have a workgroup and "become NetBIOS server" enabled on machines in my network.

Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63046/how-to-mount-mac-os-x-lion-fileshare

Comment: @bret7600 I tried following that but still no luck. Improved the detail in the question.